# Do I need to force xorg.conf usage?

Tags: 14.04, xorg, configuration, randr

My setup doesn't use `xorg.conf` by default; however I intend to create it in order to use `RandR` effectively...

Do I need to to force usage of `xorg.conf` or will Ubuntu detect and use it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to force it. Xorg server automatically loads it if it exists. You may think of it as a static override configuration.

Keep in mind that Xorg will load dynamic setting then falls back to default if `xorg.conf` for missing item.

`man xrog.conf`

> When the Xorg server is started by the “root” user, the config file
>   search locations are as follows:
>
> ```
>    <cmdline>
>    /etc/X11/<cmdline>
>    /usr/etc/X11/<cmdline>
>    $XORGCONFIG
>    /etc/X11/$XORGCONFIG
>    /usr/etc/X11/$XORGCONFIG
>    /etc/X11/xorg.conf
>    /etc/xorg.conf
>    /usr/etc/X11/xorg.conf.<hostname>
>    /usr/etc/X11/xorg.conf
>    /usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.<hostname>
>    /usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf
> ```

`man Xorg`

> **CONFIGURATION**
>
> Xorg typically uses a configuration file called xorg.conf and
>   configuration files with the suffix .conf in a directory called
>   xorg.conf.d  for  its    initial setup.  Refer to the xorg.conf(5)
>   manual page for information about the format of this file.
>
> **Xorg  has  a  mechanism  for automatically generating a built-in
>   configuration at run-time when no xorg.conf file or xorg.conf.d files
>   are present.    The current version of this automatic configuration
>   mechanism works in two ways.**
>
> The first is via enhancements that have made many components of the
>   xorg.conf file optional.  This means that information that  can  be 
>   probed  or    reasonably deduced doesn't need to be specified
>   explicitly, greatly reducing the amount of built-in configuration
>   information that needs to be gen‐    erated at run-time.
>
> The second is to have "safe" fallbacks for most configuration
>   information.  This maximises the likelihood that the Xorg server  will
>   start  up  in    some usable configuration even when information about
>   the specific hardware is not available.
>
> The  automatic  configuration support for Xorg is work in progress.
>   It is currently aimed at the most popular hardware and software
>   platforms sup‐    ported by Xorg.  Enhancements are planned for future
>   releases.

Comment: Thanks Sneetsher. Personally I can't believe I didn't look into man...